# git pre-push no such file or directory

Tags: linux, git, fatal-error, githooks, git-push

Just created a new pre-push file with the name "pre-push" under the path "myProjDir/.git/hooks"

While trying to `git push --dry-run` i'm getting the next error:

```
fatal: cannot run .git/hooks/pre-push: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Is the file `.git/hooks/pre-push` a simple text file with LF line endings? Is it executable? What shebang does it have? Can it be run directly from the command line?

Comment: #!/bin/bash
-rwxrwxrwx pre-push*

cannot be run from the command line

pre-push: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: "*cannot be run from the command line*" The same error? "No such file or directory"? "*CRLF line terminators*" That must be fixed with a tool like `dos2unix` or such. I usually use `vim` to convert using `:set ff=unix`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the type of the "pre-push" file

I just copied the pre-commit file, renamed it to pre-push, changed the code inside and now it works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
chmod 711 .git/hooks/pre-push
```